# mkdir error file path does not exist in python

Tags: python

please guys am a beginner in python and was trying to create a simple to-do-list program, but am stuck right now at the point of making directory. I will be posting the code below all suggest to help and make it better is welcome.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def_directory = "~/Documents/"

def fi_le():
    x = int(input("Enter The Length of Your To-Do-List: "))

#this next line of codes should generate the number of list you want
xf = list(range(1, (x + 1)))

#This next liine asks for the To-do list name
import os.path
directory = def_directory
namer = input("Enter File Name: ")
file_name = namer + ".txt"
file_path = os.path.join(directory, file_name)

if not os.path.isdir(directory):
    os.mkdir(directory)

f = open(file_path, "w+")

#This next line of code takes in user To-Do-List
for i in xf:
    l = ("=>" + str(i) + ". ")

f.close()

def dir_check():
    print("\n")
    print("*NOTE: PLEASE NOTE YOUR DEFAULT DIR FOR SAVED FILE IS THE 'DOCUMENTS FOLDER'")
    print("IF YOU WANT TO CHANGE DIR ENTER 'C' TO PROCEED ELSE ENTER 'D' TO USE DEFAULT FOLDER")
    print("\n")

ask_user = input("Do you want to Proceed with DEFAULT FOLDER: ").upper()

if ask_user == "D":
    fi_le()

elif ask_user == "C":
    user_folder_name = ("~/" + input("Specify Folder Name: "))
    def_directory = user_folder_name
    fi_le()

else:
    print("Please Enter 'D' Or 'C' to Continue")
    dir_check()

dir_check()



print("\n" * 5)
print("===============> End <===============")
```

Comment: At what line is the error being raised? Also in `xf = list(range(1, (x + 1)))` you are referencing a local variable in `fi_le()` from the global scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues

- 1. Indentation is important
- 2. You need to define directory variable as a full path:

  For instance: in Unix system:

  ```
  def_directory = "/Users/PycharmProjects/StackOverFlow-pip/"
  ```
- 3. You are actually not writing to the file. To write you need to call `write` function.

  ```
  for i in xf:
      l = ("=>" + str(i) + ". ")
      f.write(l)
  ```

Full corrected Code:

```
def_directory = "/Users/PycharmProjects/StackOverFlow-pip/"


def fi_le():
    x = int(input("Enter The Length of Your To-Do-List: "))


    #this next line of codes should generate the number of list you want
    xf = list(range(1, (x + 1)))

    #This next liine asks for the To-do list name
    import os.path
    directory = def_directory
    namer = input("Enter File Name: ")
    file_name = namer + ".txt"
    file_path = os.path.join(directory, file_name)

    if not os.path.isdir(directory):
        os.mkdir(directory)

    f = open(file_path, "w+")

    #This next line of code takes in user To-Do-List
    for i in xf:
        u = input("Enter the value")
        f.write(("=>" + str(i) + ". " + u))

    f.close()


def dir_check():
    print("\n")
    print("*NOTE: PLEASE NOTE YOUR DEFAULT DIR FOR SAVED FILE IS THE 'DOCUMENTS FOLDER'")
    print("IF YOU WANT TO CHANGE DIR ENTER 'C' TO PROCEED ELSE ENTER 'D' TO USE DEFAULT FOLDER")
    print("\n")

ask_user = input("Do you want to Proceed with DEFAULT FOLDER: ").upper()

if ask_user == "D":
    fi_le()

elif ask_user == "C":
    user_folder_name = ("~/" + input("Specify Folder Name: "))
    def_directory = user_folder_name
    fi_le()

else:
    print("Please Enter 'D' Or 'C' to Continue")
    dir_check()

dir_check()



print("\n" * 5)
print("===============> End <===============")
```

Output:

```
=>1. Eat Hamburger=>2. Eat Cheeseburger
```

Comment: thanks for your responds, but this section of the code on prints out the list of number but does not allow user input, how can i go about it to get user input on each printed number.  ' for i in xf:
        l = ("=>" + str(i) + ". ")
        f.write(l) '

Comment: @GideonSunday I have updated my answer, see `u = input("Enter the value")` inside for-loop. Now the method takes input from the user and prints out the text.

Comment: thanks alot but i have one last question how can i get the users when am running the program on a different pc from mine. thanks

Comment: Well, the easiest way I guess using teamviewer to reach your pc, then you run the program let users use the program. Though I don't know another way

Answer (score 0):

Possible issue is that the intermediate directory does not exist. If that is the case, use `os.makedirs` instead of `os.mkdir`.

See documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs

Answer (score 0):

Additionally of [Ahmet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5404226/ahmet), you should not do this kind of check before creating a directory on the file system:

```py
if not os.path.isdir(directory):
    os.mkdir(directory)
```

instead, you should try to create it directly, and manage the exception:

```py
try:
    os.mkdirs(directory)
except FileExistsError:
    # do something
```